# magic square algorithm without array (C)

Tags: c

I am  trying to solve magic square problem using c programming language. But when I run the below code nothing happened. what is wrong with it ?

Here is my code

**Logic:**

1. Ask user to enter size of magic square
2. Loop through total size
3. Get the position of number 1
4. Also get the position of other numbers

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
        {
          int col,row,i,size,totalSize;
          printf("please enter size of magic box\n");
          scanf("%d",&size);
          totalSize =size * size ;
          printf("total magic square size %d\n",totalSize);
          for(i=1;i<=totalSize;i++)
          {
                if(i==1)
                {
                  row =1;
                  col=(size+1)/2;
                }else if(((i-1) % size) == 0){
                  row++;
                }else{
                  row--; col--;
                  if(row == 0)
                   row = size;
                  if(col == 0)
                   col = size;
                }
                gotoxy(col,row);
           printf("%d",i);

          }
          return 0;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened"? Did it not even ask you for input?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but please notice that u are using totalSize without init it first

Comment: `totalsize` is uninitialized !

Comment: @interjay the screen disappear quickly

Comment: Depending on your environment, the console window may be closed automatically when the program terminates. Is that what you mean? You can add a scanf("%c) call to wait for a character from stdin and only then terminate the program

Comment: @o_weisman That's only a band-aid. Generally, you should run console programs from the terminal.

Comment: @remyabel I don't understand what you mean by that, sorry

Comment: @o_weisman The OP is using `conio.h`, which is a [non-standard Windows header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h). So most likely they're compiling and running their console program in an IDE which doesn't have a 'press enter to continue' prompt. The solution isn't `scanf` or `cin.get()` or whatever, but to encourage the OP to run their console program where it belongs, in a console.

Comment: @remyabel I take it you mean using Klas Lindback's first suggestion? Actually that would be more cumbersome in my opinion as normally you'd like to debug programs when you write them so running them from the environment is more convenient, but maybe I misunderstand your intention or just lack some knowledge in the matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to your development environment. It seems like, in your IDE, when the program ends, the program window is closed.

There are two ways to work around the problem.

The first way is to compile your program into an exe file and run it from a cmd window.

The second way is to introduce a delay before the program ends. You could insert a call to `sleep` for a number of seconds or `read`/`scanf` something from standard input.

I ran your program and instead of printing at coordinate col, row I printed `(col, row) i`.

The output looked like this (looks fine to me):

```
please enter size of magic box
3
total magic square size 9
(2, 1) 1
(1, 3) 2
(3, 2) 3
(3, 3) 4
(2, 2) 5
(1, 1) 6
(1, 2) 7
(3, 1) 8
(2, 3) 9
```